# Why does calling my home-rolled (reduce) function with a macro affect future calls to the function?

Tags: macros, scheme, guile

**Background:** I was working on a project in **guile 1.8.8** scheme a few weeks ago and, being a little rusty, I forgot about the built-in `(reduce)` function, so I rolled my own.  A little later, I ran into what seemed to be a hopeless bug, where calling a function with no side effects changed the flow of the rest of the program (working properly and passing a few unit tests vs. crashing completely) AFTER the function had long since returned.  Several pieces of code which used to return something like `(A B C D)` were now returning only `(A)`, causing a multitude of problems.

**Minimum working example:** After several days of whittling, I cornered the problem into this small piece of stand-alone code:

```
(define (my-reduce fun ls)
    (if (null? (cdr ls))
        (car ls)
        (my-reduce fun (cons (fun (car ls) (cadr ls))
                             (cddr ls)))))

(format #t "~a "  (my-reduce +   '(1 2 3)))
(format #t "~a "  (my-reduce or  '(1 2 3)))
(format #t "~a~%" (my-reduce +   '(1 2 3)))
```

Which prints out `6 1 1`, instead of the expected `6 1 6`.

**Additional observations:**

- Setting the second line to a `+` yields the expected `6 6 6`.
- Setting the second line to `and` yields `6 3 3`.
- Additional lines of `+` after these produce additional `1`s or `3`s depending on what the second line is set to.  So, the sequence `+` `or` `+` `+` leads to the output `6 1 1 1`.
- Additional lines of `and` or `or` after the first do NOT switch the output back.  So, if the sequence is `+` `and` `or` `+`, the output is `6 3 3 3`.  It seems as though, once I've passed `or` or `and` to `(my-reduce)`, the function becomes permanently "stuck" having that as its argument.
- I also notice that passing `and` or `or` to the built-in `(reduce)` function causes a type-error, since they are technically macros and not functions.
- Along those same lines, I notice that swapping out `or` for `(lambda (x y) (or x y))` yields the expected output.  Therefore, it seems that the critical thing here is that passing macros to my home-rolled reduce function causes an issue.

**Question:** What is going on here?  Why does calling `(my-reduce)` with `and` or `or` cause such unexpected behavior?  Does it have to do with the fact that those "functions" are actually macros?

Thanks in advance for any help.  This one has really stumped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it yourself, you can't pass `and`, `or` as parameters where a function is expected because they're *macros*, and will complain with a "bad syntax" error. In fact, I can't understand how this even works for you:

```
(my-reduce or '(1 2 3))
```

The only way I can think of is that you redefined `and`, `or` as functions somewhere, and *that* is the source of the problems. As a side note, `my-reduce` (understood as a fold-right operation) can be implemented in a more standard way like this:

```
(define (my-reduce fun ls)
  (if (null? (cdr ls))
      (car ls)
      (fun (car ls)
           (my-reduce fun (cdr ls)))))
```

The above assumes that the list is non-empty, if that's not always the case, the usual is to pass as parameter an initial value:

```
(define (my-reduce fun init ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      init
      (fun (car ls)
           (my-reduce fun init (cdr ls)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I implemented `my-reduce` as being left-associative because as per [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/SRFI_002d1-Fold-and-Map.html) page it seems standard for only the right-associative one to be explicitly labeled as such.  And yeah, I knew it assumed a non-empty list, it was a bit of a hack, since I knew I would never pass an empty list.

Comment: Now, a clarification question: Are you saying that passing a macro where a function is expected yields undefined behavior?  If so, could you link the relevant documentation?  Otherwise, I don't think I can give this the green check, since it doesn't fully answer "Why does calling (my-reduce) with and or or cause such unexpected behavior?"

Comment: (Also, I did not redefine `and` and `or`, I'm running the code exactly as it appears in the MWE.  Did it crash in your implementation? That would seem to point to it being undefined behavior.)

Comment: It's not undefined or unexpected behaviour, it's just that you're trying to pass the wrong type of object, hence an error is raised. `my-reduce` is expecting a function as a parameter, macros are not functions - they have different evaluation rules, and can't be passed around in the same way that a function is.

Comment: In my interpreter (DrRacket), `my-reduce` fails before executing, when it detects that `or` is passed as a parameter. It never even prints `1`. My point: there is nothing wrong with your `my-reduce` (apart from a weird implementation that creates a list when it shouldn't).

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted explains why the results change between invocations, I even tested it in Guile and unsurprisingly I get an error when trying to pass `or` as a parameter: `"source expression failed to match any pattern in form or"`. So definitely there's something different specific to your environment, that makes it impossible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help.  Out of curiosity, what version of guile are you using?  I'm running 1.8.8.  Perhaps it's a bug in the interpreter.  In any case: `it's just that you're trying to pass the wrong type of object, hence an error is raised.`  No error is raised, the code runs cleanly.  Therefore, I expect a more complete answer is possible, in principle -- one that links to the doc and says "here is what *should* happen when you pass a macro where a function is expected".  Would it be acceptable site etiquette to leave the question open for a bit to see if such an answer appears?

Comment: I'm using Guile 2.2.4, see if upgrading to a more recent version fixes your problems :) . Because what you're doing _should_ raise an error, for sure. I doubt this is stated in the documentation, but of course I could be wrong :) . It's ok to wait a couple of days for a better answer to appear, just don't forget to come and check it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I was so far behind the latest version, I would have upgraded sooner!  I guess I'll page through the documentation to see what it say about this.  Then again, even if it's a bug, if it's not the most recent version, it doesn't matter much, so maybe I'll just take your word for it :P  Thanks again! :)